# Microsoft Translator API Doesn't Work Cross-server

Tags: php, ajax, microsoft-translator

does this API just not work via cross origin resource? My CORS headers are set in .htaccess and verified working, because I do get a response from the API, but it's an unknown error.

I set everything up and tested on a single test server and it all works. But my prod environment requires two separate domains, one which is a CMS where the pages are hosted, and then a separate PHP server where I'm hosting the PHP side of the app that makes the CURL requests. When I try to make a CORS request, I get

```
{"error":{"code":500000,"message":"An unexpected error occurred. If the error persists, report it with date/time of error, request identifier from response header X-RequestId, and client identifier from request header X-ClientTraceId."}}
```

I get the same thing when I mimic a CORS scenario locally by using a XAMPP PHP server and a Gulp HTTP server.

My setup currently builds the JSON from body copy on a page, then sends that via AJAX POST to the PHP file, which then processes it, encodes, makes Curl requests to the API, then outputs the response. I then handle the data from the response again in the JS file.

Comment: add subscriptionKey to header https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#secret-key

Comment: It ended up being invalid JSON structure to the key/value pairs I was sending across for the text to be translated. Unfortunately the error it throws isn't very accurate or useful, so it took awhile to debug. Thanks though.